# The options do not work in selenium-dolphin library

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

For some reason, the options do not apply, the dolphin browser does not open in a full window, does not change the user agent and does not ignore errors. Can you tell me where the error is?

```
import selenium_dolphin as dolphin
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium_dolphin import DolphinAPI
from fake_useragent import UserAgent
import time

api = DolphinAPI('')

create_profile = api.create_profile(api.fingerprint_to_profile(name='my profile', fingerprint=api.generate_fingerprint(platform='windows')))
get_profile_id = api.get_profiles()['data'][0]['id']

run_profile = dolphin.run_profile(get_profile_id)
port = run_profile['automation']['port']

options = Options()
options.add_argument(f'--ignore-certificate-errors')
options.add_argument(f'--user-agent={UserAgent().random}')
options.add_argument(f'--start-maximized')

driver = dolphin.get_driver(options=options, port=port)

driver.get('https://intoli.com/blog/not-possible-to-block-chrome-headless/chrome-headless-test.html')
time.sleep(10)

driver. Quit()

dolphin.close_profile(get_profile_id)

delete_profile = api.delete_profiles([get_profile_id])
```

I looked at the official github page and searched the Internet, but did not find a solution